# How to get poltergeist/PhantomJS to delay returning the page to Capybara until AJAX is loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

How do I keep PhantomJS from returning the page to Capybara for several seconds to allow AJAX to finish loading?  The HTML body I am getting back is:

```
<!--div class='loading'>PLEASE WAIT WHILE PAGE LOADS</div-->
```

Which is telling me that PhantomJS returned the page before the page finished loading its AJAX assets.  Is there any way I can slow this down? I've tried using the rasterize.js solution but it looks as though any script I add to poltergeist's "phantomjs_options" hash is overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Capybara method that waits for you, assert that content is on the page that should exist on the page only after AJAX has completed. For example, if the page should say "Page loaded!" only after AJAX has completed, and assuming you're using RSpec, do this:

```
expect(page).to have_content("Page loaded!")
```

You can then safely test other things on the page that depend on AJAX having completed.

Capybara methods that wait for specified content to appear include `find` and `find_*` methods, `within`, `has_content?`/`has_no_content?`, `has_css?`/`has_no_css?`, `has_selector?`/`has_no_selector?`, `click_*`, `fill_in`, `check`, `uncheck`, `select` and `choose`. Some Capybara methods *don't* wait, including `current_path`, `visit`, `execute_script`, `evaluate_script` and node accessors like `text` and `value`. `all` and `first` wait if you give them options that give them something specific to wait for (`:count`, `:minimum`, `:maximum`, `:between`), otherwise they don't. It's quite a minefield. (I took the lists mostly from [this blog post](http://stefan.haflidason.com/testing-with-rails-and-capybara-methods-that-wait-method-that-wont/).)

There are other ways to wait (`sleep` (bad), polling the database until a change caused by AJAX appears, etc.) but using Capybara methods that wait for you is the usual and recommended way.

Comment: Ok I gave that a go however I am still getting empty body tags.  The site I am looking at is written in Angular.js and seems to be covered in "ng-cloak" tags which means it wont render anything until its ready to render everything.  Is there a way to request the page and then delay phantoms rendering of it for several seconds?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can just `sleep`in your test, but that guarantees a slow test. I really would try to find a piece of content that you can wait for. I've tested plenty of Angular this way. Also, be sure that poltergeist is [configured to re-raise Javascript errors](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization) so that you know if the page isn't being rendered because of one.

Comment: Dang i've done everything from sleeping the code after "visit" to adding rasterize.js but that but cant seem to get anything more than Mechanize or Nokogiri would get. Just things like:


    <!-- <section> -->
                <div ng-cloak="" data-ui-view="" autoscrolls=""></div>
    <!-- </section> -->

     If you have any more advice I'd greatly appreciate it cause it's been two days and I'm still at square one lol.

Comment: You can wait for the ng-cloaks to go away -   `expect(page).to have_no_css("*[ng-cloak]")`  . If it's a specific element with id "specific" you could do  `expect(page).to have_css('#specific:not([ng-cloak])')` to wait for that element to appear but without the ng-cloak attribute which would indicate it has already been processed.   To clarify something from @DaveSchweisguth answer - `first` and `all` will wait if you provide you them with one of the (:count, :minimum, :maximum, :between) options ( so they know what to wait for) and the have_current_path matcher will wait for a path to change.

Comment: Also - what exactly are you trying to do on the page, because most of Capybaras methods should wait to interact with elements until those elements are visible (ng-cloak hides them) so filling in an input, for instance, should wait until the ng-cloak has been removed anyway.

Comment: @TomWalpole thanks for clarifying when `all` and `first` wait. I included that in my answer.

Comment: Great tips guys it turns out phantomjs 1.9.7 was outdated and so with updating to 2.1 I no longer had the random bind issues.  Settings js errors to true helped me there!  Thanks again.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth In case of ajax request, Instead of to update a `div` complete body is getting updated..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually waiting for css wise on the loaded page, but the way I would do it is:

```
Capybara.using_wait_time(x) { page.find('css_here') }
```

where `x` is the number of seconds you want capybara to allow before erroring if it cannot find the css.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(page).to have_content "Page loaded!", wait: x
```